# How do I double each line of piped output?

Tags: command-line, awk, pipe

How do I double each line of input piped in?

Example:

`echo "foobar" | MYSTERY_COMMAND`
foobar
foobar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `sed p`.

```
echo foobar | sed p
```

You don't need `cat`, either:

```
sed p input.txt
# or
sed p input.txt > output.txt
```

---

**Explanation**

`p` is the `sed` command for "print."

Print is also `sed`'s *default* action.  So when you tell `sed` explicitly to print, the result is that it prints every line *twice*.

Let's say you wanted to only print lines that include the word "kumquat."  You can use `-n` to supress `sed`'s default action of printing, and then tell it explicitly to print lines that match `/kumquat/`:

```
sed -n /kumquat/p
```

Or if you only want to print the 5th line and nothing else:

```
sed -n 5p
```

Or, if you want to print every line from the 15th line to the 27th line:

```
sed -n 15,17p
```

If you want to print every line *except* lines which contain "kumquat," you could do this by just deleting all the kumquat lines, and letting `sed`'s default action of printing the line take place on non-deleted lines.  You wouldn't need the `-n` flag or an explicit `p` command:

```
sed /kumquat/d
```

`sed` works on a simple pattern—action syntax.  In the above examples, I've shown line-number-based patterns and regex-based patterns, and just two actions (print and delete).  `sed` has a **lot** more power than that.

I should really include the most common and useful `sed` command there is:

```
sed s/apples/oranges/g
```

This replaces every instance of "apples" with "oranges" and prints the result.

(If you omit the `g`lobal flag to the `s`ubstitute command, only the first instance on every line will be changed.)

---

Further reading (highly recommended):

- [Sed - An Introduction and Tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/sed.html)

Comment: You may wish to add what `p` does.

Comment: @sjsam, good point; done.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat input.txt | awk '1;1' > output.txt
```

edit: this is joepd's less verbose version, original below

```
cat input.txt | awk '{print $0 "\n" $0}' > output.txt
```

Comment: `... | awk '1;1' ...`